# Dynamic proxy_pass for stream

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

I'm trying to have openresty to reverse proxy TCP dynamicaly using lua.

For the start, I have :

```
    stream {
        server {
            listen     9291;
            set_by_lua_block $proxy '
                ngx.var.proxy = "10.128.128.3:8291"
            ';
            proxy_pass $proxy;
        }
    }
```

But openresty -t says:

> nginx: [emerg] "set_by_lua_block" directive is not allowed here in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:129

I found many docs on dynamic proxy_pass, but all for 'http'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [balancer_by_lua_block](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#balancer_by_lua_block) directive.
You will need to use [ngx.balancer](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md) API within balancer_by_lua_block.

Read all docs carefully. There are a lot of smart details.
But all you need is here, just RTFM.